# How to Fill a DataSet, that has a XML Schema

Tags: c#, xml, dataset

This is for college so I don't want someone to just do it for me, just need some help in understanding which way to go.

Anyway, I need to export information from my database into a XML file, obeying the rules provided by a XML Schema. The solution that I went with, is not working, and I don't know if it's because it's the wrong solution or if I'm missing a step.

Basically I create a DataSet and load my XML Schema into it.
Then I get the DataTableCollection from the DataSet, and fill each DataTable with the respective data.
The problem I'm having is that the XML file that I create after, does not obey the relationship rules.

The code is as follows:

```
/*
  there's code here to make the query to the database
  basically, it's selecting a stored procedure that returns several 
  inner joined tables, with different columns data that I'll need to put
  in the XML file
*/   

SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

/*
   there's code here to make sure that there's data
*/                    
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.ReadXmlSchema("XML_Schema.xsd");            
FillTables(dr, dataSet.Tables);
string xml = ds.GetXml();
```

As for my FillTables code, I simply get each DataTable from my DataTableCollection, and to each DataTable I add the corresponding data containted in my SqlDataReader. An example is this one:

```
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { dr["tt_id"],dr["cod"],dr["ticketState"],dr["ticketDescription"]});
```

After all this, I have a XML file, that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<NewDataSet xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ticket status="Closed" ticketId="aaa" type="LF1010">
    <description>...</description>
  </ticket>
  <owner email="1" name="zarolho" ownerId="uEmail1">uEmail1</owner>
  <supervisor email="aEmail2" name="pp" technicianID="2">2</supervisor>
  <type_type name="Login Failed" typeId="LF1010">LF1010</type_type>
 <actions/>
 <action endDate="14-01-2016 02:31:52" beginDate="14-01-2016 02:31:52" orderNum="1">1</action>
 <action endDate="14-01-2016 02:31:52" beginDate="14-01-2016 02:31:52" orderNum="2">2</action>
</NewDataSet>
```

When it should look like this, based on the XML example generated by Visual Studio:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ticket type="type1" ticketId="ticketId1" status="status1">
  <owner ownerId="ownerId1" name="name1" email="email1">owner1</owner>
  <supervisor technicianID="technicianID1" name="name1" email="email1">supervisor1</supervisor>
  <description>description1</description>
  <type_type typeId="typeId1" name="name1">type_type1</type_type>
  <actions>
    <action orderNum="orderNum1" beginDate="beginDate1" endDate="endDate1">action1</action>
    <action orderNum="orderNum2" beginDate="beginDate2" endDate="endDate2">action2</action>
    <action orderNum="orderNum3" beginDate="beginDate3" endDate="endDate3">action3</action>
  </actions>
</ticket>
```

The problem seems that my DataSet is not respecting the table relations, because I'm not properly filling them...I've tried using SqlDataAdapters, but it's also not working.

My code for SqlDataAdapters is as follows:

```
string query_ticket = "select cod as ticketId, ticketState as status, ticketDescription as description, ticketType as type from vi_Ticket where cod=@cod";
 SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query_ticket, con);
 adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(cod);
 adapter.Fill(ds,"ticket");

 string query_owner = "SELECT anumber as technicianID, name, email FROM dbo.Technician where anumber=2";
  SqlDataAdapter adapter2 = new SqlDataAdapter(query_owner, con);
  adapter2.Fill(ds, "supervisor");
```

But it gives me a ConstraintException

> Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating >non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.

So I'm not sure which way to continue in trying to find the correct solution to my problem.

Sorry if my question doesn't follow every rule, if you point out mistakes, I'll try to fix them or improve my question.

Comment: Hi There. As a starting point here is a very good article on what you are trying to achieve. ToXML is not going to work the way you want it without the relationships defined between each of the tables in your dataset. http://www.tomasvera.com/programming/generating-hierarchical-nested-xml-from-a-dataset/

Comment: However, you might find within the dataset that the relationships between parent and child tables do exist but I think you need to manually associate each row with it's parent. `dataSet.Tables["action"].Rows[0].SetParentRow(dataSet.Tables["actions"].Rows[0]);`

Answer (score 0):

As T Kelly said, the problem was that when I'm filling the DataTables, I'm not estabilishing the relationship between the tables.

The solution was really easy, I just had to assign an id value to the parent, and each child had to use that id as well.

```
For example, being tickets the parent table

dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { dr["tt_id"],dr["cod"],dr["ticketState"],dr["ticketDescription"],id});

and for a child of tickets, like owners, I would have to use that same id in the end, so that the relationship was estabilished.
```

Thanks for the help guys.